# SIR: parameter estimation and optimization here (R)

Tags: r, estimation, optimization, epidemiology, differential-equations

From here https://ourworldindata.org/coronavirus/country/israel I have extracted the Covid Data for Israel, with some manipulations, I have obtained the plot of the daily new infections in Israel
If I want to create a SIR or SEIR model, e.g.

```
 dS <- -beta/N * I * S
 dI <- beta/N * I * S - gamma * I
 dR <- gamma * I
```

but let's say that beta can not be a constant over the whole time, but also a parameter, i.e $\beta = \beta(\tau)$, $\beta$ does not need to change every day it would be better if it stayed constant weekly or bi-weekly. (therefor I used $\tau$ instaed of $t$). What would be efficient ways to estimate $\beta(\tau)$ from the number of daily new infections? (for sake of simplicity let gamma be constant over the whole time)

I have thought to somehow approximate the infection curve given below by polynomials or trigonometric functions, but I do not know what to after that? Because the functions would not be transmission rates at a given time $\tau$. What do I have to do to obtain the transmission rates from the fitted piecewise functions, or should I use a whole other approach?

I would like to solve it in R. Ideally I would also like to somehow optimize the solution so that it more or less fits exactly to the data.

Any suggestions and help highly appreciated

(the data can be found here https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.csv)

```
 covid <-  Covid[apply(Covid,1,function(x) {any(c("Israel") %in% x)}),]
 covid[,1] <- NULL  
 covid[,2] <- NULL 
 covid <- as.data.frame(covid)
 newcases <- diff(covid[,4])
```

[image]

Comment: You can segment the regression. Or, alternatively, use GAMs with smooth interpolation (I haven't thought about the solution, but I'm sure it's possible)